# How do I stub methods of an external ruby gem in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I'm trying to test a class method's behavior in multiple operating systems, without actually having to run the code on them.  I'm using the [OS Rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/os)

I want to test the 3 cases of this function in RSpec:

```
  def get_os()
    if OS.linux?
      return "linux#{OS.bits}"
    elsif OS.mac?
      return "mac"
    elsif OS.doze?
      return "win"
  end
```

I've created a quick test project [here](https://github.com/trinitronx/rspec-stubmock-test)

You can run this with:

```
git clone git://github.com/trinitronx/rspec-stubmock-test.git
cd rspec-stubmock-test/
bundle install
rspec
```

I tried manually overriding the `OS.*?` methods, but it doesn't seem to work.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to stub the methods like this:

```
describe "#get_os" do

  subject { TestMe.new.get_os }

  context "on a linux machine" do

    before do
      OS.stub(linux?: true, mac?: false, doze?: false, bits: 64)
    end

    it { should eq 'linux64' }
  end

  context "on a mac" do

    before do
      OS.stub(linux?: false, mac?: true, doze?: false, bits: 64)
    end

    it { should eq 'mac' }
  end

  # etc etc
end
```